# Passing variable data to other form's variable becomes null C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, null

Someone help me. I have a main WPF form called MainWindow and another WPF form called messageWindowxaml (I accidentally added a xaml lol)

so my problem is:
whenever and whatever a variable from MainWindow is to be read (say output in Messagebox) from the messageWindowxaml form, it becomes null suddenly!!! :(

I have this example:

```
userIP_click = ipArray[var2];
```

--> say it contains a 192.168.1.2 string. This variable is declared in MainWindow. (BY the way, ipArray is declared as string[1000] I don't know if this causes the error, I think not.)
If I'm going to output it on a messagebox inside MainWindow form, it shows the same correct string.

and then 
I have this in messageWindowxaml form:

```
var MainWindow = new MainWindow();
MessageBox.Show(MainWindow.userIP_click);
```

the output is blank messagebox. :( help!

Comment: You are creating new instance of mainWindow here `var MainWindow = new MainWindow();` whose members will be null obviously since its altogether new object.

Comment: then how to avoid the nullification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new instance of mainWindow here

`var MainWindow = new MainWindow();`

whose members will be null obviously since its altogether new object.

---

If `MainWindow` is main window of your app, you can get it using **Application.Current.MainWindow**:

```
var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
MessageBox.Show(mainWindow.userIP_click);
```

Comment: Done! sorry, didn't know to accept as answer, I only voted up. :)